# user Author's auto publish article joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Im trying joomla 3.0 and I just want to make the author auto publish article without approving from the admins.Is there any extension or plug in or any hacks that my author can auto publish the article?I want my user's author to auto publish.By the way I cant switch them into publisher because they have only authorized to create an article not to edit all article thank you for your help

Comment: Consider asking this on the Joomla SE site. This question _really_ feels off topic since you are looking for a tool or resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try FlexiContent. It has a lot of features including autopublishing http://www.flexicontent.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can make all the 'authors' of your website 'publishers' (these are two different user groups). Just adjust the permissions.